# Spring-data : How to query a subtype using a specification

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have three entites like this:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "TYPE")
public abstract class A
{
    // fields, getters, setters
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("B")
public class B extends A
{
    // fields, getters, setters
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("C")
public class C extends A
{
    // fields, getters, setters
}
```

I also have a repository like this:

```
@Repository
public interface ADao extends JpaRepository<A, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<A> 
{
}
```

On this repository, I have a method

```
List<A> findAll(Specification<A> s)
```

which is defined in JpaSpecificationExecutor.

My question is: 
how can I make a request using a specification on a field declared solely in B ?

Thanks in advance,
Jerome

Comment: change your type from <A> to <T extends A> and simply declare a `Specification` which returns a `Predicate` for class `B`.

Comment: You mean that I should parameterize the DAO interface ? Like this : public interface DAO<T extends A> extends JpaRepository<T>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<T> ??

Comment: Yes (although I'm not sure how Spring Data JPA will behave then).

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work... Spring tells me that it cannot "resolve the attribute against the path".

Comment: Please update your question and post the message/stacktrace you get (including the updated code).

Comment: If your specification uses a field declared solely in B, do you expect results other than B? If you only expect B instances, you could create a Repository for B, otherwise the attribute won't be found when querying A. If you still want to use the same Specification, I fear you'll have to put you field in A, and keep it null in C.

Answer (score 1):

create a

```
@Repository public interface BDao extends ADao<B>{}
```

and

```
public interface ADao extends JpaRepository<T extends A, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<A>
```

and then inject BDao to query B types